# How can I show a timestamp in excel

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp

I am trying to add a timestamp when a change is made and I got the below Macro from a Youtube channel and I am getting an error. I am not sure if because I am using Excel- Office 365 and the video was made in 2018 but maybe you can help. Below is the code I am using and I get a "Type mismatch (Error 13)" for ("B2:AZ1000"). Do you know how to fix this?

Also, I wanted the updated time stamp to go into two columns and I am not sure if this is correct:
= Range("A,AB" & Target.Row)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myTableRange As Range
Dim myDateTimeRange As Range
Dim myUpdatedRange As Range

'Your data table Range
Set myTableRange = ("B2:AZ1000")

If Intersect(Target, myTableRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Column for the Original Date entry
Set myDateTimeRange = Range("AC" & Target.Row)

'Column for the date/time for the Last Update
Set myUpdatedRange = Range("A,AB" & Target.Row)

If myDateTimeRange.Value = "" Then

myDateTimeRange.Value = Now

End If

myTableRange.Value = Now


End Sub
```

Comment: The error occurs because you have to use `Range("B2:AZ1000")`. You are checking in column `AC` for a value; it is unclear where you want to write the time stamps to. Please do clarify because this `Range("A,AB" & Target.Row)` will not work and this `myTableRange.Value = Now` will write the time stamps to the complete range.

Comment: Just to clarify, I want the date to populate in column A & AB on the corresponding row where a change is made. That is why I put the myTableRange = ("B2:AZ1000") as to find any changes anywhere in that range but Excel doesn't appear to like the format.

Comment: `Range("A,AB" & Target.Row)` isn't valid because you'd end up with (e.g.) "A,AB5" instead of "A5,AB5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful not to re-trigger your handler when you add the timestamps, and you need to account for the possibility that multiple rows might be updated.

Here's one way you can do it:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rw As Range, rng As Range
    
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B2:AZ1000"))
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo haveError
        Application.EnableEvents = False '<< don't re-trigger this event handler
        For Each rw In rng.Rows '<< loop each affected row
            With rw.EntireRow
                'Range references below are scoped to the row, 
                '    and so are *relative* to that row...
                If .Range("AC1").Value = "" Then .Range("AC1").Value = Now
                .Range("A1,AB1").Value = Now
            End With
        Next rw
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    Exit Sub
haveError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True '<< make sure this is re-enabled
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks again. I have been trying to figure this out for days. One more question, what would I do to have the time stamp have the seconds too?

Comment: You just need to change the cell format for those columns to include seconds - eg `m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again!